# Coordinates of nearby parking lots, findable by street name

Tags: geospatial, transportation, parking

I am looking for open latitude, longitude data with information about parking lots.

I am looking for data or an API with an open source client library, using which I can specify a **street name**, and get in return **information about legal parking lots on that street**.

Especially parking lots in the country Israel, planet Earth.

Comment: For which platform, operating system country, etc.  Need a lot more information in your question. As it is an answer that the ERB3000XVX system runs on a quantum 3 supercomputer and correctly reports that the whole of Mars can be regarded as a parking lot.

Comment: Except on alternate Tuesdays

Comment: I specified the requirements. You have a good sense of humor.

Comment: It seems like you are looking for library to build into your code? Then say so, please (don't let us play the detective who has to interpret that out of your *It will be used in phone application.*)

Comment: Yes, I am looking for open source library, using which I can specify street and it will return information about legal parking lots on the street.

Comment: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:amenity%3Dparking

Comment: @Undo To me this question (asking for a library) sounds more fitted to Software Recommendations than Open Data. Anyway, now it is here so I will transform this into an on-topic Open Data question. Sorry nni6 answers will be data, not software. I suggest opening a small discussion about this at http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com to see whether there are thing we can improve in our workflow. Cheers!

Comment: @philshem make that an answer instead of a comment pls :)

Answer (score 4):

Just to expand upon @philshem's comment: the [OpenStreetMap API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API) can be queried for tags (keys and values) like `amenity=parking` to find points of interest within a given bounding box or near a certain coordinate: an [exemplary query](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/gjR) (on overpass turbo, an interactive site to develop and preview queries) yields the following result:

[image: overpass turbo query result for parking lots in a city]

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @odjo.

For a commercial solution, check out https://coord.co/

> Coord enables software applications to connect with transport options
>   like ride-hail, bike-share, and car-share.

[image: Coord API listing]